# How do I solve ? $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{{2\cos x}}{{x + 3}}$

Tags: calculus

When I see $2\,cosx$ do I assume they want me to change it to a value? If that is the case, what value would that be?

Comment: $$\frac{2\cos0}{0+3}=?$$

Comment: Direct substitution 2/3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You know that  $\lim_{x \to 0}x+3=0+3=3$ and $\lim_{2\cos x}=2\cos 0=2$, so:

$$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{2\cos x}{x+3}=\frac{\lim_{x \to 0}2\cos x}{\lim_{x \to 0}x+3}=\frac{2}{3}$$

Answer (score 2):

The function
$$f(x)=\frac{2\cos x}{x+3}$$
is continuous except at $x=-3\ne 0$, so
$$\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)=f(\lim_{x\to 0}x)=f(0).$$